# Deciding Optimal number of cassandra nodes with a seed nodes of 3 and replication factor 3

Tags: cassandra

I am working on creating a cassandra cluster.

Our system is write heavey and planning use 3 seed nodes and total of 10 cassandra nodes (including 3 seed nodes).

We are using replication factor of 3 and consistency level QUORUM.

Is there any consideration of odd/even number of cassandra nodes based on replication factor / no of seed nodes.?

Answer (score 1):

The number of seed nodes is unrelated to the replication factor. The seeds are used when a new node joins the cluster. New nodes consult the seeds to get their initial configuration and learn the addresses of the other nodes. You need 2-3 seeds to provide redundancy, that's all.

The replication factor indicates how many nodes have copies of the data as you probably know. RF=3 means three nodes have copies of data. Consistency level QUORUM means that 2 nodes need to reply to the coordinator (because 2 is a quorum of 3). This has nothing to do with the number of nodes in the cluster, as long as you have more than 3 nodes for RF=3! Even/odd doesn't matter, number of seeds doesn't matter.